# Editing view for multiple models with the same foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

Pretty new to **Django**, so apologies in advance. I have the following models, Reservation is for a particular reservation at a hotel. Each `Reservation` has related a `Housekeeping` model for each day of the stay:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    arrival_date = models.DateTimeField()
    departure_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Housekeeping(models.Model):
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    housekeeping_status = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

I am trying to create a single editing view that shows a form for all the `Housekeeping.housekeeping_status` booleans for a certain `Reservation` and allows one to update them.

I have tried using the generic UpdateView class but got nowhere, does anyone know how one would do this? Or perhaps an alternative way of setting up the problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Django does this pretty much out of the box with Formsets. I found this page to be quite useful:

https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html

These are the kind of obstacles self-teaching brings.